# Which is better struts's validator framework or javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

What is more secure and advantageous client side validation using javascript or
server side validation using struts validator framework..???
I am working on e-commerce application

Comment: Client-side validation and server-side validation serve different goals. Server-side validation is a must, client-side validation is only for user convenience and saving traffic.

Comment: Client side validation is utterly untrustworthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not compare both since both have different scopes and use-cases

I will strongly suggest to go with both, client side validation are more with respect to user centric and showing some general error to user but do not provide deep level of data checking for the user inputs.

Go ahead with server side validation before triggering any of your business logic which always help to maintain data consistency.

Comment: Its okey with validation on both client and server side. But isnt it produce load of the processing on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `What is more secure and advantageous`, i will suggest you use `JSR 303` bean validation. You annotate your entities or beans with annotations like `@NotNull` etc and use this [Hibernate Validator plugin for Struts 2](http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/). You can now replace the `validation` interceptor with the interceptor this plugin provides. This is both advantageous in terms of not repeating yourself and not dealing with numerous validation xml files.

Comment: that is more of a server side validation

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi But it's more secure and advantageous.

Comment: server side validation is always secure and should always be there but with today's use UI centric approach java-script based validation also have its great use case

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Having a `javascript` validation is not a bad idea. Based on the question `What is more secure and advantageous client side validation using javascript or server side validation`, i will go with `Bean Validation` since this is more secure and will give the developer the flexibility of handling validation in one place without repeating himself. I think that is the whole essence of `JSR 303`.

Comment: The Struts2 OVal Plugin (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/OVal%20Plugin) supports JSR-303 validation and is still actively maintained by Apache.  Also, it is more speciic to validation than the Hibernate plugin mentioned (which also hasn't had a release or any activity in over a year).